# Counting and sum by two layers

Tags: qgis, query, overlay

I am using QGIS 1.8.

I have two layers, both polygons. Layer 1 consists of propertiers, where ID is individually names. Layer 2 consists of lakes. The query I want is:

Total count of squaremeters of lakes for each property in layer 1. And an output with the results for each output. Maybe as add to the already existing table in layer 1?

Tablestructures with area-info are ready go. I just need s tool and guide how to do it.

Comment: We need to know what software you are using.

Comment: Of course :-) Q-GIS 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Intersect* Layer 1 and Layer 2 (Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Intersect)
2. Dissolve result from step 1 (Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve). Use name of properties/ id of properties as dissolve field.
3. Add new field to result from step 2 and calculate area:
   [image]